# Getting number of failed login attempts sins last successful login / CentOS 7

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, login

Trying to create a custom login statistical welcome for SSH login session
but would like to keep the original message too, which is :

```
Last failed login: Sun Feb 19 03:52:25 CET 2017 from 125.x.x.x on ssh:notty
There were 41 failed login attempts since the last successful login.
Last login: Sat Feb 18 19:58:07 2017 from 109.255.x.x
```

but when I'm creating `/etc/profile.d/shell_welcome.sh` file for my custom script, the original one do not loads any more.
Is there any way to keep it ? 
or
how to replicate the same message?
specifically this part :
`There were 41 failed login attempts since the last successful login.`

Comment: If you were here I'd ask you to share your script part with us, in case it errored out or otherwise caused `/etc/profile` to exit early.